# Prevent NSKeyedArchiver throwing exception without Objective-C

Tags: swift, nskeyedarchiver

On iOS version lower than 11 the throwing `archivedData(withRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:)` is unavailable, so I have tried to do the equivalent on versions less than iOS 11:

```swift
let archiveData: NSData
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    archiveData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(
        withRootObject: rootObject,
        requiringSecureCoding: true
    ) as NSData
} else {
    NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: userActivity)
    let mutableData = NSMutableData()
    let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWith: mutableData)
    archiver.requiresSecureCoding = true
    archiver.encode(rootObject, forKey: NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey)
    if let error = archiver.error {
        throw error
    }
    archiver.finishEncoding()
    archiveData = mutableData
}
```

However, when the `rootObject` calls `NSCoder.failWithError(_:)` in the `encode(with:)` function an `NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException` exception is raised.

If I subclass `NSKeyedArchiver` as such:

```swift
final class KeyedArchiver: NSKeyedArchiver {

    override var decodingFailurePolicy: NSCoder.DecodingFailurePolicy {
        return .setErrorAndReturn
    }

}
```

It instead raises an `NSInternalInconsistencyException` exception with the message `Attempting to set decode error on throwing NSCoder`.

Is there a way to do this kind of archiving without throwing an exception, short of writing an Objective-C function to catch the exception and throwing it as an error?

Comment: The `.decodingFailurePolicy` is effective only on decoding (unarchiving via `NSKeyedUnarchiver`), not encoding. What is the error that the `rootObject` produces, and why? If the error would be detectable up-front, the best way to avoid this would be to not even attempt encoding — otherwise, you're likely going to need to catch the exception in Obj-C.

Comment: That makes sense, I failed to spot it was the *decoding* policy! This code is for an open source framework so I don't know if the `rootObject` will produce an error or not, so I wanted to be as safe as possible on iOS versions prior to 11.0. I was hoping I wouldn't have to use Obj-C but it sounds like I don't have any other choice. Thank you for your comment :)

Comment: Okay — given that additional info, let me turn the comment into an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're still getting the exception at encode time is that the `.decodingFailurePolicy` is effective only when decoding (i.e., unarchiving via `NSKeyedUnarchiver`), not encoding. Any object that calls `.failWithError(_:)` on encode will still produce the exception.

Calling `.failWithError(_:)` at encode-time is relatively rare: usually, once you have a fully constructed object at runtime, it's not terribly likely that it should be in a state that's not encodable. There are of course cases where this is possible, so you really have two options:

1. If you're working with objects you know and can check ahead of time whether they're in a valid state to encode, you should do that and avoid encoding invalid objects altogether
2. If you're working with arbitrary objects which you can't validate up-front, you're going to have to wrap your callout to `NSKeyedArchiver` via an Objective-C function which can catch the exception (and ideally `throw` an `Error` containing that exception, like the newer `NSKeyedArchiver` API does on your behalf)

Based on your comment above, option 2 is your best bet.

---

As an aside, you can shorten up your fallback code to avoid having to construct an intermediate `NSMutableData` instance:

```c
let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver()
archiver.encode(rootObject, forKey: NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey)
archiveData = archiver.encodedData
```

The default initializer on `NSKeyedArchiver` constructs a new archiver with an internal mutable data instance to use, and `NSKeyedArchiver.encodedData` property automatically calls `-finishEncoding` on your behalf.